# Using DBShortcut to run a jdbc query in Python in Maximo - Getting unicode error - BIRT doesn't get error so how to process the error

Tags: jython, resultset, maximo

I am running a jdbc query and using the result set to retrieve column values.
My output goal is a csv.
I am using Jython scripting in Maximo via the automation scripts.
I notice that I frequently get errors writing lines out and in the middle of output I get missing or truncated values from the point of error.
The errors read basically:

BMXAA7837E - An error occured that prevented the BIALOCHIERREP script for the BIALOCHIERREP launch point from running.
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128) in  at line number 224
psdi.util.MXApplicationException: BMXAA7837E - An error occured that prevented the BIALOCHIERREP script for the BIALOCHIERREP launch point from running.

- It seems logical that some data coming in from the database is not UTF-8 if I am seeing this error
- I know that other processes such as BIRT are able to read this very same data and get by the 'errors'

So is there a recommended way of getting by this or determining for sure whether the data is good or bad in the source database? I am currently somewhat immersed in trying to find the bad data using debug statements.

Comment: It looks like your script has an invalid character in it. On line 224, position 16, you have a Unicode character that it can't convert to ASCII (because it is Unicode). It looks like you have a non-breaking space there (a fake space) and you need to make it a normal ASCII character (like a real space).

Comment: Thank you. At this point I have directly changed any occurrence of this 'fake space' to a real space which alleviated the symptoms I previously saw. I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running SQL directly against the database, I would check whether your database has `cast()` or `convert()` functions you can call to do that conversion to ascii for you.